# Twitter: Include The Tweet ID In The Query String of a URL In The Tweet

Tags: twitter

I am trying to create a URL that will be shared in a tweet that references the tweet that it is included in, so that the page the URL is referencing can refer back to the original tweet.

I know this is a bit of a chicken and egg question, since the Tweet ID doesn't exist until the tweet is created, but I was hoping twitter had some kind of 'tweet id token' that I can include in the tweet that will be replaced by Twitter once the tweet is created. I've looked through the API as best as I could and have not been able to find any such feature.

Am I missing something, or has someone found another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The statuses/update endpoint does return the new tweet and that new tweet does have the new id. If you wait for the call to return, you can grab the id and then build the URL.

Comment: The problem with that is the URL I'm trying to build needs to already be in the tweet. I can't build it after the fact.

Comment: You won't be able to do that with Twitter. Here's some info on how they generate IDs with Snowflake and you'll see that it's really not possible:  http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html